# database update using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to update my data if it is false it will go back to editadmin.php but if it is success it will go to successfullyupdateadmin.php but when i click the button, there is nothing happen, my model method is updateadmin

this is in my controller with session

```
function index(){

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        $data['Id'] = $session_data['Id'];
        $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
        $data['Name'] = $session_data['Name'];
        $data['Password'] = $session_data['Password'];
        $data['Email'] = $session_data['Email'];
        $data['Gender'] = $session_data['Gender'];

        $this->load->view('EditAdmin', $data);

    } else {

    redirect('welcome', 'refresh');

    }
}

function updateadminz() {

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required|alpha|max_length[6]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('EditAdmin');

        } else {

            $id = $this->input->post('Id'); 

            $username = $this->input->post('Username'); 
            $name=$this->input->post('Name'); 
            $password = $this->input->post('Password'); 
            $email = $this->input->post('Email'); 
            $gender = $this->input->post('Gender'); 
        }

        $this->load->model('model_adminlogin');

        $result=$this->model_adminlogin->updateadmin($id, $username, $name, $password, $email, $gender);

        if($result == True) {

            $this->load->view('successfullyupdateadmin');

        } else {

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

This is my model

```
function updateadmin( $id, $username, $name, $password, $email, $gender) {

    $data = array(
        'Username' => $username, 
        'Name' => $name, 
        'Password' => $password, 
        'Email' => $email,
        'Gender' => $gender 
    );

    $this->db->where('Id', $id);
    $this->db->update('admin',$data);
}
```

This is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Edit Admin</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <meta name="description" content="Edit Admin,Online High School Enrollment">
        <meta name="author" content="NMSC, Bernal Developers">
        <?php echo link_tag('images/icon1.png', 'NMSC Icon', 'image/ico'); ?> 

        <link href="<?php echo base_url("dist/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css"); ?>" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url("adminoption/index")  ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span> Back </a> 
                </div>

                <div>
                <p class="nav navbar-text "> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo "&nbsp&nbsp" .$Username ;?></p>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("home/logout") ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <h3 class="giv">Edit Admin</h3>
        <div class="wrap">

        <form  action="<?php echo site_url("editadmin/updateadminz") ?>" method="POST">


            <label class="label-info input-lg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Id:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <input class="" type="text" name="Id" value="<?php echo $Id ?>"  readonly=""> <br>                                           
            <label class= "label-info input-lg ">Username:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" value="<?php echo $Username; ?>" size="70"><br>

            <label class="label-info  input-lg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" size="70"><br>

            <label class="label-info  input-lg">  &nbsp;Password:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" value="<?php echo $Password; ?>" size="70" ><br>

            <label class="label-info  input-lg">  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>" size="70"><br>

            <label class="label-info  input-lg"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Gender:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="Gender" id="Gender" value="<?php echo $Gender; ?>" size="70"><br>

            <br>    


            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-info z" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>

        </form>

        </div>

        <script src="<?php echo base_url("js/jquery-2.1.4.js"); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url("dist/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as your Controller Function:

```
function updateadminz() {

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required|alpha|max_length[6]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('EditAdmin');

        } else {

            $id         = $this->input->post('Id');

            $data = Array(
            'Name'      => $this->input->post('Name'), 
            'Password'  => $this->input->post('Password'), 
            'Email'     => $this->input->post('Email'),
            'Gender'    => $this->input->post('Gender') 
            );

            $this->db->where('Id', $id);
            $this->db->update('admin',$data);

            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this->load->view('successfullyupdateadmin');
            }
        }
    }
}
```